# Customizing optimizer in pytorch lightning

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Here I have implemented a custom optimizer in normal pytorch. I am trying to do the same thing in pytorch lightning but don't know how to.

```
def run_epoch(data_iter, model, loss_compute, model_opt):
    "Standard Training and Logging Function"
    start = time.time()
    total_tokens = 0
    total_loss = 0
    tokens = 0
    sofar = 0
    for i, batch in enumerate(data_iter):
        sofar = sofar + len(batch.src)

        output = model.forward(batch.src, batch.trg,
                            batch.src_mask, batch.trg_mask)
     
        loss = loss_compute(output, batch.trg_y, batch.ntokens)
        loss.backward()
        if model_opt is not None:
            model_opt.step()
            model_opt.optimizer.zero_grad()

        total_loss += loss
        total_tokens += batch.ntokens
        tokens += batch.ntokens
        tokens = 0
    return total_loss / total_tokens



class CustomOptimizer:

    def __init__(self, model_size, factor, warmup, optimizer):
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self._step = 0
        self.warmup = warmup
        self.factor = factor
        self.model_size = model_size
        self._rate = 0

    def step(self):
        self._step += 1
        rate = self.rate()
        for p in self.optimizer.param_groups:
            p['lr'] = rate
        self._rate = rate
        self.optimizer.step()

    def rate(self, step=None):
        "Implement `lrate` above"
        if step is None:
            step = self._step
        return self.factor * (self.model_size ** (-0.5) * min(step ** (-0.5), step * 
               self.warmup ** (-1.5)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = create_model(V, V, N=2)


    customOptimizer = CustomOptimizer(model.src_embed[0].d_model, 
    1, 400,
    torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0, betas=(0.9, 0.98), 
    eps=1e-9))

    for epoch in range(10):
        model.train()
        run_epoch(data, model, 
                  LossCompute(model.generator, LabelSmoothing), 
                  customOptimizer)
```

I tried my best to follow the pytorch lightning official documentation and the code below is my attempt. The code does run smoothly without error. But the losses in each epoch goes down very slowly. So I use the debugger in pycharm and find out that the learning rate of `customOptimizer` at line `customOptimizer.step()` always stays as the same value "5.52471728019903e-06". Whereas in the implmentation in normal pytorch shown above does successfully change the learning rate as the training goes on.

```
class Model(pl.LightningModule)
    def __init__(self, ....) 
        self.automatic_optimization = False
        :
        :
        :
   :
   :
   :
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9)
   

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):   
        optimizer = self.optimizers()
        customOptimizer = 
        CustomOptimizer(self.src_embed[0].d_model, 1, 400, 
                          optimizer.optimizer)  
        batch = Batch(batch[0], batch[1])
        out = self(batch.src, batch.trg, batch.src_mask, batch.trg_mask)
        out = self.generator(out)
        labelSmoothing = LabelSmoothing(size=tgt_vocab, padding_idx=1, smoothing=0.1)
        loss = labelSmoothing(out.contiguous().view(-1, out.size(-1)), 
               batch.trg_y.contiguous().view(-1)) / batch.ntokens
        loss.backward()
        customOptimizer.step()
        customOptimizer.optimizer.zero_grad()
        log = {'train_loss': loss}
        return {'loss': loss, 'log': log}



if __name__ == '__main__':
    if True:
        model = model(......)
        trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=5)
        trainer.fit(model, train_dataloaders=trainLoader)
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, in `training_step` you are first creating a new instance of `CustomOptimizer` and then doing a `customOptimizer.step()` on it. For every training step, you create a new instance which starts with a `step = 0`. This makes the entire calculation in the `step()` function static and your learning rate remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you it works.

````
class Model(pl.LightningModule)
    def __init__(self, ....) 
        self.automatic_optimization = False
        self.customOptimizer = None
        :
        :
        :
   :
   :
   :
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9)
   

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):  
        if self.customOptimizer = None:  
           optimizer = self.optimizers()
           self.customOptimizer = 
           CustomOptimizer(self.src_embed[0].d_model, 1, 400, 
                          optimizer.optimizer)  
        batch = Batch(batch[0], batch[1])
        out = self(batch.src, batch.trg, batch.src_mask, batch.trg_mask)
        out = self.generator(out)
        labelSmoothing = LabelSmoothing(size=tgt_vocab, padding_idx=1, smoothing=0.1)
        loss = labelSmoothing(out.contiguous().view(-1, out.size(-1)), 
               batch.trg_y.contiguous().view(-1)) / batch.ntokens
        loss.backward()
        self.customOptimizer.step()
        self.customOptimizer.optimizer.zero_grad()
        log = {'train_loss': loss}
        return {'loss': loss, 'log': log}



if __name__ == '__main__':
    if True:
        model = model(......)
        trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=5)
        trainer.fit(model, train_dataloaders=trainLoader)```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `loss.backward()` and return only the computed loss.

If you want to make special operation before or after, you can use `on_before_backward()` and `on_after_backward()`.

Some changes to make when using Lightning:
[changes when using Lightning](https://pl-bolts-doc-images.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/pl_docs/pt_trainer_mov.m4v)

Using many optimizers for the same architecture: [example](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/3346#issuecomment-756476073)

I hope this can help you build your own model.